# Delete old MySQL records every hour

Tags: php, mysql, events, triggers

Suppose I include the built in MySQL timestamp into my fields on my database table.

Everytime I update the records it will update the timestamp.

I would like to delete records than are older than an hour.
Any ideas for how best to do this?

I could have a loop checking the timestamp for all records or perhaps a trigger in the database?

Comment: Sounds like you need a cron job

Comment: How soon after the records become stale (i.e. have not been updated within the past hour) must they be deleted?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a cronjob to schedule a query to be executed in  a fixed time interval:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE time_created < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 3600);
```

Every time it's run, it will delete all records older than 1 hour (which is presumably what you want).

Comment: @Lemonio: Yes. `time_created` is a Unix timestamp (int).